# Azure git push returning 403

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

This morning I wired in deployments via git for my Azure app.  I setup git deployments for the app which gave me a git clone URL.  I set that URL as a new remote for my git repository and named it `azure-qa`.  The first time I pushed, git asked for credentials which I had set in Azure.  Everything has worked perfectly from the start.

I just tried to push again via the command `git push azure-qa master` and I get the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://MYUSER@MYSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/MYREPO.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

When I try to hit https://MYSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net/ directly, I'm not prompted for my deployment credentials.

Why am I, all of the sudden, getting a 403 and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem and will post the answer for posterity.  I ran `git fetch azure-qa master` and then re-ran my remote push and it worked.  I have no idea what there would be to fetch because I'm the only developer doing development on that remote...