# Getting 403 forbidden while accessing Azure repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops, http-status-code-403

Getting 403 forbidden while accessing Azure repository. Am a member of the project team and other documents are accessible except repository.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901802/azure-git-push-returning-403 will this post resolve your issue?

Answer (score 5):

It might be caused by your account not being set to an access level that allows code contribution (for example, a **Stakeholder** account doesn't allow access to code).

Take a look at [About access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=vsts) for a detailed explanation on the available access levels in **Azure DevOps**.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your user's access level is Stakeholder.You must change it to Basic or other.

Stakeholder does not have access to repository.

See below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

Answer (score 0):

Also it's possible to get an 403 when the authorization tokens is expired, you can use your preferred git tool to reauthorize your account against devops remote repo.